# Question About Negative and Positive Convexity

Tags: bond, duration, convexity

I read the following paragraph from investopedia:
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/convexity.asp
If a bond's duration increases as yields increase, the bond is said to have negative convexity. In other words, the bond price will decline by a greater rate with a rise in yields than if yields had fallen. Therefore, if a bond has negative convexity, its duration would increase—the price would fall. As interest rates rise, and the opposite is true.

If I understand correctly, for a vanilla bond with coupon, its duration is always a negative value, right? When investopedia says "If a bond's duration increases as yields increase", it is saying the absolute value of duration increases, is that right?

Comment: Duration is expressed as the inverse for conveience or you’d see a lot of negative signs. A normal bond therefore has “positive” duration which means prices rise as yields fall. Price Change=-1*duration*rate change

Answer (score 1):

If you're long a normal Vanilla bond, you're always long Duration and long Convexity. You get negative convexity if you are **short** the bond.

Convexity has an effect on the **rate** at which you make or lose money:

Negative convexity (you are short the bond) means that the **rate** at which you lose money **increases** as yields decrease. And the rate at which you make money **decreases** as yields go up. So being short convexity is not as good as being long convexity.